# "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup" Using TTF and SDL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Here is the full error code:

```
------ Build started: Project: PongGame, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
main.cpp
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function "int_cdecl SDL_main(int,char * * * const)" (?SDL_main@@YAHHQAPAPAD@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function "int __cdecl SDL_main(int,char * * * const)" (?SDL_main@@YAHHQAPAPAD@Z)
MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
C:\Users\Robbie\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PongGame\Debug\PongGame.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and here is my main:

```cpp
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    // Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    // Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see this my main is very basic, I have not really even started coding, but this error is very annoying!
I have my subsystem set to console, and here are my additional dependencies:

```
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib
SDL2_ttf.lib
```

Comment: Please show your code here, not on pastebin. Indent by four spaces or click `[{}]` button in the editor.

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm including different things and have different inputs